# entire information printed on one line

Tags: html

I made a django file and in the html I show some information to the user however the whole paragraph of information is printed on a single line I tried putting a div around them but it didn't help. I want the information to be displayed as a normal article instead of the whole thing on one line. I think it might have to do with the sizing of some div but im not able to point my finger at whats the exact problem. ps I've tried to cut the code short, thats the reason its so untidy.

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container" >
<div class="pl-5 ">
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div id="parent" >
          <div class="">
            <br>
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" height="75" width="75" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
          </div>
             <div>
              <div class="container">
                <a  class="mr-2 text-secondary" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}"> <h4>{{ post.author }}</h4></a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
              </div>
               <div class="container">
              {%if post.author == request.user%}
              &nbsp <a  href="{% url 'post-delete' post.id %}"> <i title="Delete Post" class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a> &nbsp |  <a  href="{% url 'post-update' post.id %}">edit</a>
              {% endif %}
               </div>
           </div>
      </div>   
            <div class="ml-3 ">
              <div class="container">
            <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
            {% load static %}
            {% if post.image %}
            <div class="container">
            <img id="media" style="max-width:95%;height:auto;" class="" src="{{ post.image.url }}" >
            <div>
              <div>
            <a href="{{ post.image.url }}"><button class="btn mt-2 mb-2"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i>

</button></a></div>  
            </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
</div>




<style type="text/css">

.deletebutton {
  font-size: small;
  color: hotpink;

 }
 #viewallcomments{
  font-size: medium;
 }
 #container {
    width: 500px;
}
#first {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#second {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#third{
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
#clear {
    clear: both;
}
 #reportcontainer {
    width: 100%;
}
#reportfirst {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}
#reportsecond {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}

</style>
</div>













































{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is displayed in a single line? I tried your code (in a plain HTML file with a long paragraph) and was not able to reproduce your problem. I replaced every placeholder with a long lorem ipsum, but the line breaks work correctly.

Could you provide the final HTML which is rendered in the browser? Maybe your text contains non-breaking spaces instead of spaces?

However, your container has a width of at least 500px. Until this point the text won't break in any case.

Edit: The style for the container references an element with the ID "container". But such an element does not exist, as "container" is just used as class. Maybe there are some differences between your sample above and the code you are actually using?

Answer (score 1):

use the css attibute "white-space" on the containing div.

you can try

"white-space: pre-line"

or

"white-space: normal"

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: not working, I checked the other things in the document too. thats not it